# Setting td colspan to half spaces

Tags: html, css

The title is a little misleading but I want to set the colspan of a table cell to a half integer. I know this can't be done so I was thinking of adding a blank cell after each real cell. Then setting colspan = 8 should give me what looks like a half space.

Ie [1][][2][][3][][4]
   [--------]

Will this work  or is there a better way?

Comment: Unclear to me what you actually want to achieve …

Comment: Can you upload a real image of what you want or some live code please